# WordPress migration from live server to localhost having 404 error?

Tags: migration, localhost, xampp

I'm trying to have a copy of my WP site from live server to localhost and have followed all the steps on tutorials I could find, but I seem to get a 404 error at the end.

I am using XAMPP and Windows 10

Steps that I have taken:

1. Backed up my entire WP folders from hostgator and put in my sub directory in htdocs.
2. exported a .sql file from phpmyadmin.
3. imported the .sql file to my local phpmyadmin.
4. change the url to localhost/myfolderrootname in wp_options
5. edit `config.php` to store the new database credentials
6. I was told to delete the `.htaccess` file. I did that too but nothing changes.

The local copy of the site actually loads, the theme is there and it displays a custom 404 that defaults with the theme. However going to any pages such as `localhost/myfolderrootname/wp-admin` or `localhost/myfolderrootname/websitepage` it displays "Object not found! and 404 error". Literally out of options here guys and would appreciate any help!

Comment: Lots of things could still be wrong, but debugging from a distance without access to the actual host is even more difficult than when you're on it. In any case, this problem is not WP related. Stack Overflow might be a better place to ask.

Comment: I have access to the host.

Comment: But I don't, so I can only take wild guesses at what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wp_options` isn't the only place you need to change the link, do the following :
Go to the live site and download the plugin WP Migrate DB, it has really good interface so you will make it from there. The plugin will change all links and give you exported .sql file with them, without changing anything in the live site, then import the new database to localhost, delete or rename your `.htaccess` file on the localhost enviroment I personally put `~~` before the dot, and make sure to go to `127.0.0.1/exampledir/wp-admin` and save your permalink structure to generate new `.htaccess` file.

Comment: It seems like there are many other places to change the links? Can't i not do it through sql querys? Or is it too many!

Comment: You can do it with SQL Query, but this plugin is really your best option, in my opinion, it is really lightweight you can install it, export the db and uninstall it, it is absolutely free, and it's one of this plugins which cleans after itself.